# R changing rdata file names when importing

Tags: r, import, rdata

I am trying to load two rdata files, **InvoiceDetail20210818A** and **InvoiceDetail20210818B**. However, R imports the **InvoiceDetail20210818A** file into my environment and automatically names it **InvoiceDetail20210818B**, but when I open the file, it contains all the data for the **"A" file**. When I load the actual **InvoiceDetail20210818B** file, it correctly names it **InvoiceDetail20210818B** in the environment with the data from the **"B" file**. There are no errors when I load the files, and I have tried deleting the existing **"A" rdata file**, and creating a new rdata file, but I am still encountering this issue. Does anyone know why this would be?

Code:

```
load("~/InvoiceDetail20210818A.rdata")
```

What my environment looks like:

[image: my R environment]

What the dataset looks like when I open it:

[image: what the dataset looks like]

EDIT: Thank you to Panagiotis Togias in the comments, who said that "Saving an object in .RData format, saves also its assigned name. I would assume that before exporting to .RData, your file was loaded to env with the wrong name". I renamed the dataset as ending in "A", then re-saved it as an rdata file and now it is loading with the correct name.

Comment: Saving an object in .RData format, saves also its assigned name. I would assume that before exporting to .RData, your file was loaded to env with the wrong name. In general, it's best to export to .RDS instead.

Comment: @PanagiotisTogias that must be it! I renamed the dataset as ending in "A", then re-saved it and now it is loading correctly. Thank you!